# Match/case for checking the expression results not matching pattern in Scala

Tags: scala, match

This is the Scala code to check what container contains the label.

```
var typeName:JString = ""
if (stringTypes.contains(label)) {
  typeName = "string"
} else if (floatingTypes.contains(label)) {
  typeName = "float"
} else if (encodingTypes.contains(label)) {
  typeName = "encoding"
} else if (rangeTypes.contains(label)) {
  typeName = "range"
}
```

Can I make it better with match/case or similar? I see that the match/case matches the pattern not checking if the expression returns true or not. So, the following code does not work.

```
val typeName = label match {
  case rangeTypes.contains(label) => "range"
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of repetition going on there.  I actually try to use pattern matching or if-else chains as a last resort.  Functional programming works best when you're working on containers rather than syntactic structures, so I would do it by putting the type-to-string mapping into a `Map`, like:

```
val types = Map(stringTypes   -> "string",
                floatingTypes -> "float",
                encodingTypes -> "encoding",
                rangeTypes    -> "range")

types find (_._1 contains label) map (_._2) getOrElse "label not found"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use *guards*:

```
val typeName = label match {
  case label if rangeTypes.contains(label) => "range"
  ...
```

or create a custom `unapply` method:

```
object TypeName {
   def unapply(label: String): Option[String] = 
     if (rangeTypes.contains(label)) Some("range") 
     else if(floatingTypes.contains(label)) Some("float")
    ... else Some("") // this means that you won't have a MatchError but an empty string if nothing matches
}

val TypeName(typeName) = label
```